# Autolinking keywords in text with tags

Tags: categories, tags, seo

Sometimes in my posts I use the keywords that exists in my tags and categories list.
Is it possible to automatically link the keywords in texts with the tags and categories?
Or should do it manually ? I will use this in my SEO practices.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is plugin that will automatically link to tag / category pages if similar keyword is used in the post.

-- [SEO Smart Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-automatic-links/)

Comment: Cool! That is what I needed.